# How to attach battery wires that got detached from this circuit board?

Tags: batteries, pcb, circuit-design, battery-charging, wire

Not an electrical person (at all!), but looking for some guidance as I feel this could be an easy fix.

[image: circuit board]

This piece belongs to a kid's camera that only works when it's plugged via USB. When you unplug, it turns off. When I unscrewed I noticed that the black and red wires were not attached to the B+ B-

[image: battery]

I remember seeing the black wiree near the B- one and the red wire near the B+ one, but I'm not sure if they go underneath the letters in those silver things or on the right/left side of the letters. How would I get them to stay? I read hot glue is a way I attempted with the black wire tape but that didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a friend with a soldering iron?

Comment: I can ask, but do you know where the cables go?

Comment: Solder is used to connect these. I don't see any other way to make a good connection in this case. Tape definitely won't work.

Comment: If you know someone who can solder electronics they probably have enough knowledge to fix this. Shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: by the way, don't let the metal ends of the black and red wires touch each other or both touch a metal thing. Wouldn't be a bad idea to wrap tape around each one to prevent accidents. This type of battery *really* doesn't like short circuits.

Comment: Interesting, I actually purposely cut the wire to expose the metal ends thinking they needed to touch. I'll wrap them with black wire tape. Thx

Comment: 99% sure yes but I would iike your friend to check the polarity with her multimeter just to be positive (pun intended). A short or reverse connection can cause irreperable damage.

Comment: If the black and red wires touch each other, you'll short out the battery, and this is a type of battery with a propensity for bursting into flame when shorted.

Comment: @Awsmike the metal ends do need to touch the circuit board in the right places. They just shouldn't touch each other (or the same metal thing) or else it's a short circuit.

Comment: Saw your other post.  You should consider finding somebody who knows how to solder.  If you screw up and accidentally short circuit those wires, things can get pretty "exciting" pretty quick.   You don't want that happening in a childs toy for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal convention is red goes to B+, black to B-

You can and should use a voltmeter to verify that the red wire is positive and black negative, in the rare case that someone didn't follow the convention.

In the photo the large pad where they connected one of the wires is connected to the pad marked B-

They probably just connected it there because it was a little easier than soldering to the smaller B- pad, and it's the same circuit trace.

You need to remove the old solder and bits of broken off wire from the board and resolder the wires to the pads, make sure the wires are trimmed down and make a nice clean solder joint. If you've got someone experienced to do it for you they should know what to do.

I've circled where the wires were connected.
[image]

Comment: ok so the wires goes to the pads! red to left pad and black to right pad. regarding the "old solder and bits of broken off wire" where do you see that? is that on the right/left side of the letters? i have to remove those?

Comment: See the blob to the right of where it says B+? That's where the red wire goes. It's a small solder pad. To the right of that is another small solder pad, that one is B-. Normally the black wire would solder there, but they soldered it to one of the larger pads below. Those a both connected to B-, you can see the lighter green parts, those are the circuits, they have a green coating except for where something is supposed to be soldered. Those two lumps are the solder and parts of the wire that broke off. DON'T connect both wires to the large square pads, it will short the battery.

Comment: @Awsmike Added your photo with the connections circled.

Answer (score 0):

Using black wires for minus and red for plus is a very long and well known tradition in the electrical community.  (these aren't cables, that word means multiple wires in a common plastic, rubber or other sleeve).

The way these were previously attached and may be attached again by an experienced person is to use an electronics soldering iron to melt the blob of "tin" (actually a mixture of tin and another metal), putting the already tin-covered wire end into the blob and allowing the blob to harden again, all in a matter of 1 to 5 seconds for each blob.  But for quickly trying it out, you can purchase packs of 10 colored wires with small "crocodile clamps" on the ends that can be clamped onto the blob at one end and the battery wires at the other, experts often use these to test out things first.  "crocodile clamps" are intentionally sharp to cut through thin layers of "dirt" on the metal.

To further ease this soldering process, it is normal to simultaneously apply a "flux" chemical to the blob.  "flux" is a chemical that dissolves surface "dirt" on the metal blob and metal conductors, thus letting the metal flow more freely.  Electronics flux can be purchased separately, but the most common way (in electronics) is to purchase a roll of unused "tin" thread, that is actually hollow with an appropriate amount of semi-solid flux rosin in a hollow space inside.  Thus when the fresh tin is melted onto the connection, the flux rosin melts and mixes with the freshly melted "tin".

The most common "tin" for soldering such small electronics is 1mm thick or even thinner.  The traditional (but somewhat toxic) "tin" mixture is 63% actual tin mixed with 37% lead (which is the toxic part).  This mixture melts at a lower, more practical temperature and hardens into a nice blob that doesn't tend to grow "whiskers" of metal that can short to other metal connections in the device after years in outer space (NASA worries about that).  More modern devices, especially those legal to sell as toys, use lead-free metal mixtures, such as 96.5% tin and about 3% copper and/or silver.  Shops (online or real world) specializing in selling parts for electronic hobby and repair generally stock 2 or more ready made types, the safe ones will loudly advertise themselves as "lead free".

To do the melting, a tool called a "soldering iron" is used.  Historically, this was a pointy piece of actual iron, covered in layer of "tin solder" and mounted in a handle (to not burn your hand as much).  The iron would be heated over an open fireplace until hot enough, then quickly moved to the puddle or other item to be melted.  Modern soldering irons are hollow and contain an electrical heater inside that can heat them as high as about 500 degrees C (900 degrees F), but it is usually enough to set a lower heat level, as the tin mixture will often melt at slightly over 200 degrees C (400 F) and then a few dozen more degrees are needed to actually heat up the wires and other metal parts.  Fancy "soldering irons" are connected to a thermostat and can be set within 10 to 20 degrees margin.  But there are also simpler "thermally balanced" irons where the heat escaping into the air around the tip will balance out the capacity of the electrical heater to keep the tip at a useful temperature (usually the temperature for tin/lead mixture, but it is quite possible they now make them for tin/silver/copper mixtures).  For the small blobs in the photo, I would recommend a balanced iron with an 18 to 30 W heater, or a thermostatically regulated iron with a 40 to 70 W heater (that is turned off half the time).  Whichever you buy, make sure the tips are cheap and easy to replace, as they wear out, especially for beginners, but even professionals will use up a lot of tips, and the holders in which you put the burning hot iron will often have a place to store a few spares.

The practical process is somewhat easily learned, and there are many online videos showing how it is done, with helpful narrators explaining what to do etc.  For example, the look of the "dried" blob will be somewhat different depending if it was done at the right speed or not (doing it a the wrong speed or with the wrong amount of flux will result in a weak connection called a "cold solder join", even if the problem isn't too low a temperature).  If this is someones favorite toy, practice the skill first on some pieces of thin electrical wire from the same shop, learning the basics takes a few days of practice.

Other tools needed for a simple job like that:

1. Small pliers with thick plastic handles to not burn yourself.
2. Small side cutters to cut wires and other excess metal.
3. A cheap wet sponge (like for kitchen cleaning) to clean the tip of the hot iron.
4. A big bucket of ice cold water for when you burn your hand, scar usually disappears after a few weeks of pain.
5. A fireproof work surface such as a ceramic table, a 1 sq foot concrete paving tile, or an old dinner plate.
6. An old coffee mug to hold hot items (such as the soldering iron) without causing a fire.

Comment: You don't want to just melt the existing solder blob and put the wire in it, that blob has bits of the old wire still in it. It should be removed and fresh solder applied.